# How to pass a variable in JavaScript if in view it's empty?

Tags: php, html, ajax, laravel

So, I created a report system, but in the last step, I have a little problem...In JavaScript I'm using a variable from database for Ajax, but when a post has no comments, I'm getting `Undefined variable: key`.

**Here is my script**

```
if (isset($key)){
    $('#yourFormIdComment{{$key+1}}').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
    method:'POST',
    url:'/career_report_comment',
    data:data,
    success: function (result) {
            // do something with result
        }
    });
    });
}
```

**Here is my view with variable**

```
@foreach($opinionComment as $key => $comments)
    <div class="news-v3 bg-color-white">

<h4 style="font-size: 13px">
        {{ $comments->user->username }}</h4>
    <p>{{ $comments->comments }}</p>
        <ul class="post-shares post-shares-lg">
<li @if ($key === 0) class="active" @endif  style="float: right;left: 20px;bottom: 30px"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalComment{{$key+1}}" href="javascript:void(0)" ><i class="rounded-x icon-flag"></i></a></li>
</ul>

        </div>
@endforeach
```

My question is...how can I pass the variable `{{$key+1}}`from script even if a post has no reviews/comments?Because this is happening only when I have comments on a post.

Comment: You cant pass data you dont have. You can do a check if the data isset or empty so you are sure you pass on data you actually have. If the data is empty redirect them to the page were the data is created

Comment: Yes, I want to make a check, if variable isn't empty, run this code...`if ( $key == null( { code }`, but this isn't working.

Comment: if (isset($key)) {code}, this checks if the var is set, or you can do you check but instead of using == use !=

Comment: @Collin , please check my updated script, because now I have save undefined key :(

Comment: What do you get when you dd($key) within your if(isset(key)) statement

Comment: nothing happens with `dd($key)`; .  `$key` isn't defined in controller, only in view, here `@foreach($opinionComment as $key => $comments)`

Comment: just dd($opionComment) in that case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrew i after talking in the comments and checking your code i might have found a solution to your problem.

You get a error:

```
Undefined variable: key
```

You get that error because the key isnt defined.

```
if (isset($key)){
    $('#yourFormIdComment{{$key+1}}').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
    method:'POST',
    url:'/career_report_comment',
    data:data,
    success: function (result) {
            // do something with result
        }
    });
    });
}
```

In the first part of your code you use the variable $key, but the key is defined within the foreach in the second part of your code. That's why you get the error.

Comment: The problems is that in view I'm using that variable, like here `<li @if ($key === 0) class="active" @endif  style="float: right;left: 20px;bottom: 30px"><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalComment{{$key+1}}" href="javascript:void(0)" ><i class="rounded-x icon-flag"></i></a></li>
</ul>`, and I only have undefined variable on scripts section

Comment: You get that error on the scripts section because you didnt set the variable there. You only declare the variable in de foreach that is found in your views seciton. That why you cant use that variable. You could declare it with a foreach around the script.